# Protege is it possible to show the name of a property in Ontograf

Tags: sparql, rdf, semantic-web, owl, protege

I'm taking screenshots for my ontology using OntoGraf in Protege

My problem is that Onto graf doesn't put any name or lable on the property, it just uses colors, and even the colors, start to repeat. for example

[image]

the color of properties between instane0-instance1 and instance0-instance3 is the same though they are connected using different properties.

Do you know how can I show a label (or whatever text) on the property ?

Kindly note I am asking about property not instances or class (for those, I already know how)

Comment: I don't think it is possible. Perhaps you can do screenshots from the "Arc types" tab (icon with an arrow in the ontograf window) which is displaying properties and associated colors.

Comment: Duplicate as already asked on the Protege mailing list, which is obviously the most promising point to ask questions about the tool itself.

Answer (score 1):

Responding to the updated question, from all the free tools I have used so far, the one works good both to visualise and edit, is the [Cmap COE](http://cmap.ihmc.us/coe/test/v401ReleaseNotes.html#). I find it  particularly useful it:

1. Shows the list of triples in addition to the diagram
2. The existing properties appear in a drop-down list when creating new ones
3. There is clear  notation for owl object property types, e.g. "=>=>" for transitive, ">>=" for functional and so on.
4. Reads both OWL and RDF, exports in various serialisations: Turtle, N3, OWL/XML.
5. Easy HTML export
6. Multiple maps
7. It can also be used collaboratively

The [COE manual](https://encrypted.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0ahUKEwiA5dK2uvXMAhWJzRQKHU51CngQFggbMAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fcmap.ihmc.us%2Fcoe%2FCOEmanual06.pdf&usg=AFQjCNHSl5AVzTEIRISmZrYOKajF0FNwOw&sig2=5lPoYnOzmO-yoRwn9DGxwQ&bvm=bv.122676328,d.d24) is quite well written.

In some cases [OWLGrEd](http://owlgred.lumii.lv/online_visualization) may do a better job than Cmap COE.

Having said that, if there is a big A-box, both of them wouldn't work well. In that case, a tool like [Gephi](https://gephi.org/) with [SWI plugin](https://marketplace.gephi.org/plugin/semanticwebimport/) may be more appropriate (I see it featured in the answer that you pointed to. There was some reason I stopped using it, but I don't remember it as "not working").

Currently, apart from Cmap COE, I also use [LodLive](http://en.lodlive.it/) but only with SPARQL endpoint (although it is supposed to work with files as well) and TopBraid Composer ME (but visual graphs are available only in the paid version).

There are a few visualisation tools like [Wandora](http://wandora.org/), which I have't tested.